# Arithmetic expressions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have studied java and php for many years and recently just started developing in JavaScript as well. Anyway a fairly noob question but can anyone work out why this application isn't showing displaying the interest when the button is clicked? I have been using w3schools website to learn from.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Interest Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>

<fieldset>
<legend>Interest Calculator</legend>
Enter amount: <input type="text" id="amount" ><br><br>
Interest rate: <input type="text" id="interest"><br><br>
Enter years: <input type="text" id="years"><br><br>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
</fieldset>

<p id="sum"></p>

<script>

function calculate(){

var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
var rate = document.getElementById("interest").value;
var years = document.getElementById("years").value;
var sum = amount(1+rate)^years;

var message = "Your total return will be: " + sum;

document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = message;


}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks,

Adam

Comment: Don't use `w3schools`. See http://w3fools.com for more info.

Comment: I'll go out on a limb here, and guess it's the fact that `amount` is not a function, but a string ?

Comment: where did I declare amount as a function?

Comment: @user3918443 What you have done is `amount(` - That's declaring as a function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **explicitly** specify `*`. It is not normal for `5(3) = 15` in JavaScript or any programming language. You need to explicitly specify `5*(3)`:

```
var sum = amount*(1+rate)^years;
```

**Working Code**

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Interest Calculator</legend>
  Enter amount: <input type="text" id="amount" ><br><br>
  Interest rate: <input type="text" id="interest"><br><br>
  Enter years: <input type="text" id="years"><br><br>
  <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
</fieldset>

<p id="sum"></p>

<script>
  function calculate(){
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    var rate = document.getElementById("interest").value;
    var years = document.getElementById("years").value;
    var sum = amount*(1+rate)^years;
    var message = "Your total return will be: " + sum;
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = message;
  }
</script>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/lovevazaxe**

Comment: I can in 3 minutes apparently :)

Comment: Thanks @user3918443... This motivates people like us to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

The OP uses the `^` operator and presumably wants to use the power-of operator.

In javascript the `^` operator refers to [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) - I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Instead, the power-of operation is done with the [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) function.

So replace `var sum = amount(1+rate)^years;` with

`var sum =  Math.pow(amount*(1+rate),years)`